# How to get items from headers by learning from initiators and using request python?

Tags: fingerprintjs2, fingerprintjs

I am trying to get the fingerprint as can be seen from this snapshot.
[image]

I tried searching for the fingerprint but it's not in the response or cookies. I am wondering how this fingerprintjs works so that I can imitate and return the fingerprint item.

The website is https://alfagift.id/
When you take a look into network, especially categories, there's a preflight and an xhr where it is initiated by https://alfagift.id/_nuxt/ca268e7.js

I've tried doing a requests

```
resp=requests.get(" https://alfagift.id/")
resp.cookies
```

nothing seems to be returning the fingerprint that's needed.

Can anyone show me how you can get the fingerprint?

Answer (score 0):

This file's rendering and executing the fingerprinting script on the client side: https://alfagift.id/_nuxt/f9d159c.js

Proof:

```
__fpjs_d_m||Math.random()>=.001))try{var t=new XMLHttpRequest;t.open("get","https://m1.openfpcdn.io/fingerprintjs/v3.3.3/npm-monitoring",!0),t.send()}catch(t){console.error(t)}}(),[4,vt(r)];case 1:return t.sent(),[2,gt(L(ft,{debug:n},
```

Used library: https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs

Comment: How would I then get the value? Do I pass the header values through that js file to get the fingerprint? Because I don't see the value for fingerprint in any kind of response.

Comment: It's calculated on the client-side, in the browser, in JavaScript context

Comment: can we get the results?or simulate the passing of the result through client side?  because I am seeing it being returned in one of the headers in categories. How is the value returned there? You can try inspect network check the categories xhr it's there.